# Admittance of the impedance of R and C in series?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistors, impedance

I have a resistor \$R=150\$ and a capacitance \$C=\frac{1}{750\omega}\$ in series:

\$
Z=R-jX=R-j\frac{1}{\omega C}=150-j750
\$

If I take the admittance I have

\$Y=\frac{1}{Z}=\frac{1}{R-jX}=\frac{1}{3900}+j\frac{5}{3900}\$

According to my book we now have a resistor \$R=3900\$ **parallell** with a capacitance \$C=\frac{5}{3900\omega}\$. But why parallell now?

Answer (score 1):

You calculated the admittance and got a complex number. Now you have this complex number and you can interpret that number as it was a result of a calculation for the admittance of a parallel circuit (which is the reciprocal of the impedances connected in parallel).

So your book just showed you how can a series RC circuit be replaced with a parallel RC circuit.